# Ensembling with VotingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am using `VotingClassifier` from `sklearn.ensemble` however i am puzzled with the results.
Consider following algorithms:

```
alg1 = LogisticRegression()
alg2 = GradientBoostingClassifier()
alg3 = GaussianNB()
```

Then when I ensemble and fit the models with following weights:

```
eAlg = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('LR',alg1),('GB',alg2),('NB',alg3)],
                        voting='hard',
                        weights=[1,5,1])
eAlg.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred_ens = eAlg.predict(X_test)
```

I get following result:

```
np.mean(pred_ens == y_test) #0.91
```

(I am predicting only 0/1 classes)

Just for my curiosity, I put `weight=5` to GB. Doesn't it mean that even if other two classifiers says otherwise, the model will follow GB? So it should be equal to GB alone.

**Because if i train only GB alone, i get slightly higher score. 
How is that possible?**

Comment: very strange, can you get the individual predictions and find out which  records it is differing for?

Comment: Yes, i can. But that doesn't say WHY.

Comment: dont get angry, i'm trying to help, why don't you take a look a the code, use `pdb.set_trace()` see if you can isolate where the problem is occurring. if you post a minimal dataset which results in this behaviour, i can take a look as well.

Answer (score 4):

You set the `voting` parameter to `hard`. Afaik that means your `weights` array will be ignored, as it is only used with soft voting. You get lower results than with the single classifier, because the other two learned models win a vote against the "better" classifier for too many of the data points, where they are actually wrong. At least that is my guess.

Comment: You are wrong about the weights being used only in soft voting. But, overall, your post is correct - it seems that the reason for the observed behaviour is that the "wrong" classifiers over-power the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the something similar and got the expected results. In your case, this must be due to not setting the parameter 'random_state'. If you do not set a SEED or 'random_state' to the classifier definition then it results in different accuracies each time you run.Try,

`alg1 = LogisticRegression(random_state=20)
 alg2 = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=20)
 alg3 = GaussianNB()`